# Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction

Tags: android, realm, retrofit

I must push a object just with one note and to push his media files, but it do not want to do this. I do not know why is difference , but if i do this without changing notes its work fine , but I need to send just changed notes , please help. What is my problem? I need to understand why this happen

```
  private void pushMediaFiles(Task task,Note newNote, PushTaskListener listener)
{
    PushTaskModel pushTaskModel=new PushTaskModel(Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(task));
    pushTaskModel.notes.clear();
    Note oldNote = new Note();
    oldNote.update(newNote);
    pushTaskModel.notes.add(oldNote);

    service.pushData(pushTaskModel)
            .map(taskResponse ->
            {

                ArrayList<MediaFile> filesToSave = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Note note : task.getNotes())
                {
                    for (MediaFile mediaFile : note.getMediaFiles())
                    {
                        if (mediaFile.hasChanges() && mediaFile.getFileAbsolutePath() != null)
                        {
                            filesToSave.add(Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(mediaFile));
                        }
                    }
                }


                return filesToSave;
            })
            .subscribe(taskMediaFiles ->
                    {
                        Log.d("PUSH_TASK_EVENT","3 GOOD");

                        if (taskMediaFiles.size() == 0)
                        {
                            listener.onSuccess();
                            return;
                        }

                        for (MediaFile mediaFile: taskMediaFiles)
                        {
                            saveMediaFile(mediaFile, new OnResponseListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onStart()
                                {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(boolean successfully)
                                {
                                    listener.onSuccess();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable throwable)
                                {
                                    listener.onError(throwable);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


}
```

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(mediaFile)` who told you this is a good idea??

Comment: this is not my idea , i came to this project when this was made, I understood , file in db is not good idea, but , is too late to change this

Comment: The short answer is that, follow the exception stack trace, you are doing a Realm insert without a write transaction.